# IntelliJ IDEA: Unable to create a Gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm facing difficulties in setting up a gradle project. During setting up of the Gradle settings in the wizard,

I am not able to use the default recommended gradle wrapper because it downloads the Gradle and the network connectivity is very bad. So I go with the local gradle distribution which I have installed in my Ubuntu. On refreshing of the gradle project after creation, I always get stuck to this error. When I run the `gradle build` command through the terminal on the empty project, It works fine.

I have also tried the troubleshooting solutions given by the IDE. But, that made no improvements. Need assistance to solve this problem.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment if any additional info required.

Answer (score 0):

As no-one else has chipped in, an approach that should work is to use the [Gradle Idea Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) instead of relying on the build in support Gradle in Idea. In my experience the plugin supports a wider range of Gradle project structures than Ideasupports directly. So you would

1. Create a Gradle project outside Idea and confirm it all works on from the command line.
2. Add the Idea plugin to the project
3. Run 'gradle cleanIdea idea' to generate the Idea project files.
4. Open up the newly generated project files from Idea and off you go.